# How much data can an iframe read from its parent window?

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy

If I create a widget and embed it in an `<iframe>` on a site that is from a different domain, how much data about the parent page can the widget read?

Obviously there's no DOM access, but is there any access to other information, such as whether the parent page has a parent, or what the url of the parent page is?

Answer (score 2):

Normally the content of an iframe served from a different domain cannot access the parent in any way. It's like loading the page in a different browser tab.

However, even if served from a different domain, there is a possible man-in-the-middle attack which wil allow access to the parent DOM. This is easier than it sounds -- anyone who has administrative control over a public WiFi access point could carry out this attack (think Starbucks, hotels, airports.)

It is possible to protect against this attack using the HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute -- see below.

The man-in-the-middle attack works as follows. Suppose your page loads off http://yoursite.com and the iframe goes to http://badsite.org

- first http://badsite.org redirects to http://yoursite.com/badpage
- This is the step that requires a man-in-the-middle attack. The attacker must either be able to get between the user and yoursite.com, or control the answers to your DNS lookup.  The goal is to serve the content of http://yoursite.com/badpage from the attacker's site, not your actual site.
- The attacker can then serve whatever malicious code they like from the (fake)  http://yoursite.org/badpage. Because this is in the same domain as the main page, it will have access to the parent DOM.

The HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute seems to be the way to avoid this. You can read the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox), but the best description might be [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx).

This seems to be supported on [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/05/security-in-depth-html5s-sandbox.html), [IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx), [FireFox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341604), [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html).

The spec says that if the "allow-same-origin" attribute is *not* set, "the content is treated as being from a unique origin." This should prevent your child iframe from accessing  any part of the parent's DOM, no matter what the browser thinks the URL is.

Sandbox also lets you disable scripts, pop-ups, the ability to change the top level URL, and other things.

Answer (score -2):

I did a little google search, and it turns out that normally you *cannot access the internal guts of the Iframe if the the content is another domain (same origin policy)*, however there's an [article here](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) which can give you some ways around that.